# How to perform sql query on sheets of excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, sql, query

I have two tables in excel(sheets) . One has 10,000 entries , another has 1000 entries . Both of them have account number column in common . I want to select only those row in 10,000 entries which have their account numbers specified in 1000 entries table. An easy way is preferred .

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In.  A Query can import data from an Excel table.  The Merge command can join two Queries together, with an option to only include matching rows.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/merge-queries-HA104149757.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103993872

So for your scenario I would first build a Query for the 1000 row table.  Then I would start a new Query for the 10,000 row table, add a Merge to the first query and check the option to Only include matching rows.  You can deliver the result to a new Excel Table.

Answer (score 0):

import both into access into separate tables.  We will name them 10k and 1k for obvious reasons.

then you can directly execute this command and your done:

select * from 10k,1k where 10k.accountnumber=1k.accountnumber;

Otherwise you might try a pivot table in excel.